# How can I filter an array of objects by its Date property showing only last stored objects per each day?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have an array of objects `[{createdAt: Date, value: Int}]`. On each day there could be a lot of objects added to array. I need to filter this array by showing only one last stored object per each day.

**For example:**

```
let data = [
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T22:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T21:00:00.000Z"), value: 3},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T20:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T02:00:00.000Z"), value: 4},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T09:00:00.000Z"), value: 3},
];
```

**Required Output :**

```
let result = [
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T20:00:00.000Z"), value: 1}
];
```

Any ideas how can I make it the most cost-effectively?

just in case here is my solution:

```
const rawResult = data.reduce((prevValues, item) => {

                    let day = item.createdAt.getUTCDate();
                    let month = item.createdAt.getUTCMonth();
                    let year = item.createdAt.getUTCFullYear();
                    let date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;

                    if (!prevValues[date] || (prevValues[date].createdAt < item.createdAt)) {
                        prevValues[date] = item;
                    }
                    return prevValues;
                }, {});

const result = Object.keys(rawResult).map((date) => {
                    return rawResult[date];
                });
console.log('result: ', result);
```

Comment: Show the example and your efforts.

Comment: What do you mean with "last"? Last *position*, or last *time* in the `createdAt` date value?

Comment: yes, it was not very clear. I added an example. It should be the latest time per each day.

Comment: @MaxNiagolov : Removed mongoDB related tags from question, if in case your data array is being populated from mongoDB's query result then if you want this to be done at the time of DB operation(Certain things can be achieved via mongoDB itself) then please update this question with sample collection data & required o/p then add mongoDB tags otherwise this can be a js code question. but first please be sure on where you wanted this operation to happen(either in code or in db - assuming db is involved as you've primarly tagged) and tag it accordingly !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your input is not sorted, you could first choose to sort it, and then use a `Map`, keyed by the date part, to get the desired values.

This assumes that you want to group by the day according to UTC time (since you input explicitly with that timezone):

```js
let data = [
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T22:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T21:00:00.000Z"), value: 3},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T20:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T02:00:00.000Z"), value: 4},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T09:00:00.000Z"), value: 3},
];

let result = [...new Map(
    data.sort((a,b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)
         .map(item => [item.createdAt.toJSON().slice(0, 10), item])
).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash to filter you array of objects with ease.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

filterObjectsByDate() {
    this.objsFiltered = 
 this.allObjectsNunFiltered.filter(g => g.date);

this.objsFiltered = _.chain(this.objsFiltered)
  .filter(g => g.date.toString().substring(0, g.date.toString().indexOf('T')) === new Date()) // if u want to filter based on Todays date
  .value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T22:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-01T21:00:00.000Z"), value: 3},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T20:00:00.000Z"), value: 1},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T02:00:00.000Z"), value: 4},
    {createdAt: new Date("2019-01-02T09:00:00.000Z"), value: 3},
];

result=new Map()

 data.map(item=>{ 
  let dat=item.createdAt.toJSON().slice(0,10)
   if(!result.has(dat)){
     result.set(dat,item)
   }
  })
  
  solution=Array.from(result.values())
  
  console.log(solution)
```

> Output: [   {
>       "createdAt": "2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z",
>       "value": 1   },   {
>       "createdAt": "2019-01-02T20:00:00.000Z",
>       "value": 1   } ]